# Android Emulator with Google Services is not included with API 27

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm currently having an issue with testing some google services on an application I'm working on.

I'm running the Nexus 5 & Nexus 5X emulators (that include the Play store on them). Unfortunately that seems not to be true with API 27. I have downloaded the Google Play x86 Atom System image for API 27 and have restarted Android Studio and have created new emulators. I keep getting an error that the app won't run without google play.

[image: APP won't run unless you update google play]

[image: Image of SDK Platforms]

Is this a bug right now with SDK 27 Nexus Emulators or am I missing a step?

Additional info- running SDK 26 with my code produces results after updating google services. The issues is that on the emulators that should have Google play running SDK 27 do NOT have google services included.

Answer (score 0):

Play services package that is pre-loaded in the emulator is a little outdated, and you can update them IF the emulator has Play Store, but as of today it does not, so the best shot is stepping down to API 26 and perform your tests, or use a real device with API 27 if you can.

Genymotion is another great option, you can sideload google play services but again, as of today they only have API level 26 emulator.